# Order of Group with Elements of Order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let G be a finite group such that every element in G which isn't the identity has order of 2.  Show that $|G| = 2^{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I know that G is necessarily going to be abelian.  But what is a good method to prove the order of the group?

Comment: Ack! I saw that but didn't scroll to the bottom to see an accessible proof.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A good method is Cauchy's Theorem.  This is slightly more high-tech than the approach showing that $G$ is abelian et cetera, but it's a much more adaptable result.  For example, what about finite groups all of whose elements have order a *power* of $2$?